# How to make different layers of mesh in circle z-axis by grouping different meshes?

Tags: mesh

I am trying to group many meshes in a colour and aligning them together. My aim is to make a ring of colours so they have a layer or ring that will go in. I think it is a little bit difficult to explain. Please see the Picture 1 below.

[image: Picture 1]

I think you can see what I am trying to do. The inner core should be green meshes and it should be circulated by blue meshes that I have grouped and aligned together.

The end product should be like an arrow with different layers with each layer having separate mesh bricks as units.

I think you can agree that it does not look very professional and round. Is there a better way to do this rather than just copying the mesh group (see selected blue mesh second layer) and duplicating it and moving it above. How do I join two meshes on either side without doing it manually and really labouriously.

I'm new to Blender. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: instead of downvoting a new user question you should help him improve it

Comment: I'm typing that as we speak ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! You might find the tour helpful in understanding what our mission is, and what kinds of answers you can find here. In short, this is a place for people to find answers to common, generic questions. Your question is a little too specific to YOUR case, and wouldn't really be helpful to a broader audience. If you can rework your question to be more broad, that'd be great! Even as it is, though, your question would be great for the Blender Artists forum, or another forum where posts are a bit more fluid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Particle System**

[image]

[image]

A Cylinder has a Particle System.  This ensures the circular pattern. Use multiple objects with particles systems, such as a plane.  The object which owns the particle system does not need to be rendered.  The yellow [brick] is duplicated along the vertices of the cylinder.  Settings are shown in the Particle Systems Panel in the image above.  You can see many tutorial videos on particle systems on various web sites.

Click on image to see larger version.

[image]

Comment: you can add other options : array+curve modifiers  and child duplication to verts